# Narrowing down a large dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a large dictionary of real estate parcels and info. I need to write a script to narrow down the entries based on certain keys. I have already crashed spyder multiple times trying and failing to print correctly.

Here is an example of the dictionary:

```
parcels = [
  {
    "street_address": "1 CROWN PL RICHARDSON TX 75080",
    "living_area": 2984,
    "state_code": "A1",
    "market_value": 231902,
    "CAMPNAME": "ALDRIDGE EL"
  },
```

This dictionary is massive. How can I narrow down and print based on certain attributes (e.g. `"market_value" > 250000` and `"state_code" = "A1"`)? Thanks a million- I'm new to this and so stuck.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few ways you could do it.

You could use the `filter` function.

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x["market_value"] > 250000 or x["state_code"] == "A1", parcels)
```

you could use a for loop

```
filtered = []
for parcel in parcels:
    if parcel["market_value"] > 250000 or parcel["state_code"] == "A1":
        filtered.append(parcel)
```

you could use list-comprehension

```
parcels = [i for i in parcels if i["market_value"] >  250000 or i["state_code"] == "A1"]
```

Comment: great post, just change 'or' to 'and ' to meet his requirements

Comment: @BendikKnapstad We are interpreting his question differently,  I see the two examples as being two separate examples.  I don't think he literally meant `and` in a logic kind of way

Answer (score 0):

You kind of have your solution already it seems.

if you just want to print them you can use the conditions you already posted

```
for item in parcels:
    if item["market_value"] > 250000 and item["state_code"] == "A1":
        print(i)
```